# How to get a numeric value from a webelement in Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, selenium

> ```
> <div>
> id: 123456 has been successfully submitted.
> <br/>
> <br/>
> </div>
> ```

In the above code, I am able to retrieve the whole text. But I need to retrieve the id value which is 123456 here and store it in an excel sheet. Help me in retrieving the numeric value?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you wrap the number in another tag and then get that? Alternatively using a `RegEx` you can also retrieve it assuming the rest of the copy remains static.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To extract the numeric value from your string:

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(html.replaceAll("\\D", ""));
```

The regex `\D` means "any non-digit", and `replaceAll()` is deleting all non-digits by replacing them with nothing.